# How do I tell my boss that the noise he makes distracts me?

Tags: communication, work-environment, manager, noise

I am working in web development. I've recently started a new job at a small firm of 4 people. I'm the most senior person in terms of age and experience, and report to the CEO, who is younger than me.

The CEO makes an irritating noise while stirring his coffee, which distracts me. He bangs the spoon rapidly against the edges of the mug for about 40 seconds.

How can I ask my boss to stop doing this as it's noisy and distracting?

Comment: VTRO  This is not a duplicate.

Comment: Why is it any different to ask a boss to be less distracting that it would be for a coworker. If it is disrespectful to mention it to your boss its disrespectful to mention it to a coworker. - For this question not to be a duplicate I think that reason needs to be explained in the question.

Answer (score 13):

It's 40 seconds.

It's not a big deal.  Sure, people have annoying little habits, but it's no big deal.

Grit your teeth, breathe, let it go.

There, it's over.

Alternatively, just raise one eyebrow slightly and give him "The Look", while he's doing it.

Answer (score 5):

There really is no good way for you to address this without embarrassing, or worse, angering your manager **which happens to be the CEO** of the company.  I think in this case *the juice is not worth the squeeze*, and you should ignore this brief distraction.

Everyone has annoying quirks, including you most likely, so my advise to you going forward is to not sweat the little stuff.

Answer (score -3):

If you complain about something like this they will inmediately label you as annoying and they will likely link your AGE to this, which is bad because they will think you don't perform as well as younger people or that you can't handle the **stress**